# circular build in ocaml, no way around it?

Tags: ocaml, circular-dependency

so i ve got a `faction` type which has a list of `pawns`, but the `pawn` type include a record type which is a link to the `faction`

both are in a different module, on a different file. putting them on a single file would disrupt the way i organized my source and it doesnt work anyway

i don't see any way around circular build, is there a workaround?

i have tried using third module which can be the link between the two, but that seems way too unconvenient

Comment: The solution is probably to have a third module with both types defined in it. It’s often considered good style to not have circular data structures in ocaml so you might want to change the types (e.g. a `pawn` might have a `faction_name` so you can decide if two `pawn`s are in the same faction). A secondary problem you may have is if you want to call lots of functions back and forth between the modules. But in this case the modules aren’t really separate at all and shouldn’t be in separate files

Comment: It will be much easier to offer suggestions if you include code illustrating the concrete nature of your problem. I can say, given your description it seems strange to me that you’d want a pair of mutually recursive data type for this case.

Comment: the main reason why i want `pawn` inside a list of `faction` is to iterate over them, and the reason why i want `pawn`s to have a link to their `faction` is that they can get different bonuses according to their faction, but in the end i think i ve found a workaround. bascailly i made a new `faction_enum`. both `faction` and `pawn` have that inside their records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two compilation units (aka files) have mutual dependencies then the easiest way would be to factor out this dependency into a third file and make those two depend on it. An alternative solution would be to make the problematic part polymorphic, and instantiate the concrete types independently, a concept that is hard to illustrate without a good example, so if you will provide us with more insights of your code and its organizations we could be more helpful.